# Extract Polygon Data for Each Neighborhood from GIS Shape File

Tags: php, wordpress, gis, shapefile

I have a dataset that has four types of files with the following file extensions -
.DBF,.PRJ,SHP,SHX

My goal is to get all the polygon coordinates for each neighborhood and draw the boundary outline on the google map when a user is on a specific Neighborhood page. Currently the datasource for the site is a MySQL Database.

I have tried converting the shp file to Geojson but then parsing that file is time taking.

I have also tried using tools such as QGIS and shp2sql etc.

I would like to know what is the best way to get the main attributes from the dataset along with each neighborhood's Polygon coordinates.

please advise

Comment: You might want to try this question on http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If I converted the shape file to geoJson. What is the best way to parse  it since it's a huge file. I need to get the polygon coordinated where id="x" .. something like that

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to accomplish this using the ogr2ogr command line tool -

ogr2ogr -f "MySQL" MYSQL:"mydb,host=myhost,user=mylogin,password=mypassword,port=3306" -nln "world" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" path/to/world_adm0.shp

I have the polygon coordinates in a geometry field in the table attached to its corresponding neighborhood id.

I did Select ASTEXT(Shape) as POLYGON from world to get the array of coordinates and now I can convert that to json and send it to Javascript so that it can be mapped